# How to remove unique index from Dotnet EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have a model:

User

```
public class User {
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string UserName {get; set;}
 ...
 public int? ManagerId {get; set;}
 public User Manager {get; set;}
 public int? SupervisorId {get; set;}
 public User Supervisor {get; set;}
..
}
```

I have checked my MySQL Db, and found that ManagerId is unique. I didn't set it as unique. Now i want to remove that using dotnet ef migrations. How to do that ?

I use donet core 2.1 at the moment.

I have test with remove the ManagerID and Manager and do dotnet ef migrations add UpdateUser

checked and ManagerID is removed. then I tried to add again new name AssignedManagerID and it created new one with unique is true.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Users_AssignedManagerId",
                table: "Users",
                column: "AssignedManagerId",
                unique: true);
```

my Datacontext:
        public DbSet Users {get; set;}

I have no Fluent at all on OnModelCreating() for User

Comment: By default `Id` field is counted as unique, did you changed your model after applying migrations?

Comment: no I didnt change anything. I check SupervisorId is not unique. Just the managerId.

Comment: I have no problem with Id being unique just with the ManagerId shoudln't unique.

Comment: Can you try `[Index(IsUnique=false)]`? or fluent one? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes#data-annotations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EF Core is confused by the two self referencing `User` navigation properties and wrongly decides that you are trying to model one-to-one relationship between `User.Manager` and `User.Supervisor`. It (randomly) selects the `Suprevisor` as principal and creates unique FK relationship through `ManagerId`. `SuprevisorId` is not treated as FK, hence no FK relationship is created for it.

As usual when EF Core assumptions are incorrect, you should resolve them explicitly with data annotations and/or fluent API. For self referencing relationships the only option is fluent API, so add the following to your `OnModelCreating` override to create two one-to-many relationships:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOne(e => e.Manager).WithMany();
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOne(e => e.Supervisor).WithMany();
```

Comment: I used .HasIndex(c => c.AgencyId).IsUnique(false); to solve this two FKs with one unique index

Comment: @SaravananSachi Not sure what was your case, but here the problem is FK relationships misconfiguration, so it needs to be fixed exactly as shown (the problem here is *not* only the index).

Comment: my bad, I missed "two self referencing user". In my case, a table has 2 FKs from two different tables. EF creates one FK with unique index and another one with non unique index. I want both to be non unique. So I used IsUnique().

Answer (score 2):

you can try below code.

```
migrationBuilder.DropIndex(name:"IX_Users_AssignedManagerId",table:"Users");
```

Its working in my project. thanks

Comment: it works for me